# GETDATE() causing syntax error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I just created a stored procedure to insert data into a table after performing some calculations. My create procedure code is below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc] 
    @log_id INT,
    @job_nm VARCHAR(20),
    @feed_in_out_ind CHAR(1) = null,
    @process_dt DATETIME = null,
    @procedure_dt DATETIME = NULL,  
    @procedure_nm VARCHAR(20),
    @object_ty VARCHAR(20),
    @operation_ty VARCHAR(20),
    @num_records INT,
    @success_status BIT,
    @error_msg VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @start_time DATETIME,
    @end_time DATETIME = null
AS
```

When I try to call the stored proc, if I use the GETDATE() for any of the datetimes, I get a syntax error `Incorrect syntax near ')'` When I replace the GETDATE() with an actual datetime, the procedure runs correctly.

Here is my calling code:

```
EXEC myStoredProc 
    @log_id = 1, 
    @job_nm = 'It',
    @feed_in_out_ind = 'i',
    @process_dt = GETDATE(),
    @procedure_dt = GETDATE(),
    @procedure_nm = 'Test 1', 
    @object_ty = 'test',
    @operation_ty = 'test',  
    @num_records = 50, 
    @success_status = 0, 
    @error_msg = 'Hello',
    @start_time = GETDATE(),
    @end_time = GETDATE()
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
DECLARE @Now AS DATETIME
SET @Now = GETDATE()

EXEC myStoredProc 
    @log_id = 1, 
    @job_nm = 'It',
    @feed_in_out_ind = 'i',
    @process_dt = @Now ,
    @procedure_dt = @Now ,
    @procedure_nm = 'Test 1', 
    @object_ty = 'test',
    @operation_ty = 'test',  
    @num_records = 50, 
    @success_status = 0, 
    @error_msg = 'Hello',
    @start_time = @Now ,
    @end_time = @Now
```

Comment: Great workaround, but it doesn't give any explanation of the underlying problem.

Comment: That worked - Thank you. The problem is that I will be calling this procedure from many other stored procedures. I really need to understand what caused this, so it can be worked around in a less "bandaid" kind of way.

Comment: It's not a band-aid.  See "Specifying Parameters" on this page in the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915(v=SQL.100).aspx.

Comment: I have always used this technique. I don't think it is a "band-aid" or a lack of an explanation, but rather the correct way to do it.

Comment: You can also compress the first two lines as DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE()

Comment: Its because GETDATE() is a function and you cannot provide function as a parameter to the executing stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You  can't call a function in the parameters AFAIK.

Something I have used is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc] 
     @process_dt DATETIME = null

AS   

IF @process_dt IS NULL
    BEGIN       
        SET @TimeComplete = GETDATE()
    END
```

Add one of those for each of the variables you want to default to now.  Or, declare a variable at the beginning of the proc (INSIDE IT), and set all the times to that.  That way they are internally consistent (no millisecond variation between).

Answer (score 2):

Stored proc parameters take constants or NULL as defaults

From [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926(SQL.100).aspx)

> default
>
> Is a default value for the parameter. If a default value is defined, the procedure can be executed without specifying a value for that parameter. The default must be a constant or it can be NULL.

Normally I'd do `SET @dtparam = ISNULL(@dtparam, GETDATE())` in the stored proc

Comment: @JNK: Am I that bad otherwise?

Comment: Not at all.  You won't pull punches if something is incorrect, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason you are having problems is you are attempting to call a function within the parameter of a stored procedure.

It has been over a year since I researched how stored procedures worked exactly if my memory is correct you should be able to store the current time into a local variable and use that value.

I guess I was to slow to post because the "workaround" was exactly what I suggested :$